# Is non-blocking socket really non-blocking when used with blocking select()?

Tags: c, sockets, select, nonblocking

This is rather theoretical question. If sockets I/O (either `read` or `write`) is set to `O_NONBLOCK`, but then this socket is set in `fd_set` to `select()` which *blocks* (waiting for an event the file descriptor become either readable or writable), then that socket is *blocking* anyway (due to the `select()`)?

Why would I set the socket to be non-blocking, when even the blocking (default) version once become readable (or writable) (thanks to `select()`), won't block, because the `select()` said it has data to read (or write) and thus the socket is able to perform its operation with that data without blocking. So why to bother setting socket non-blocking when select() blocks anyway?

An example of having `non-block` sockets, **but** in conjuction with *blocking* `select()`:

```
#include <unp.h>

void str_cli(FILE *fp, int sockfd)
{
    int flags, maxfd, stdineof;

    fd_set rset, wset;

    ssize_t nbytes, nactual;
    //struct bufpos { char *read_ptr, *write_ptr; };
    struct bufpos ipos, opos;
    char inbuf[BSIZE], outbuf[BSIZE];

    //--//

    //set nonblocking flag for these fds:
    int nblkFds[3] = {sockfd, STDIN_FILENO, STDOUT_FILENO};
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        flags = Fcntl(nblkFds[i], F_GETFL, 0);
        Fcntl(nblkFds[i], F_SETFL, flags | O_NONBLOCK);
    }

    //initialize buffer positions
    ipos.write_ptr = ipos.read_ptr = inbuf;
    opos.write_ptr = opos.read_ptr = outbuf;

    stdineof = 0; //stdin
    maxfd = max(STDOUT_FILENO, sockfd) + 1;

    while (1)
    {
        FD_ZERO(&rset);
        FD_ZERO(&wset);
        //can read from stdin and readptr is not at the end of buffer
        if (stdineof == 0 && opos.read_ptr < &outbuf[BSIZE])
        {
            FD_SET(STDIN_FILENO, &rset);
        }
        //can read from socket and the readptr is not at then end of buffer
        if (ipos.read_ptr < &inbuf[BSIZE])
        {
            FD_SET(sockfd, &rset);
        }
        //difference in outbuf == data to write to socket
        if (opos.read_ptr != opos.write_ptr)
        {
            FD_SET(sockfd, &wset);
        }
        //difference in inbuf == data to write to file
        if (ipos.read_ptr != ipos.write_ptr)
        {
            FD_SET(STDOUT_FILENO, &wset);
        }

        Select(maxfd, &rset, &wset, NULL, NULL);

        if (FD_ISSET(STDIN_FILENO, &rset))
        {
            switch ((nbytes = read(STDIN_FILENO, opos.read_ptr, &outbuf[BSIZE] - opos.read_ptr)))
            {
            case -1:
                perror("read");
                if (errno != EWOULDBLOCK)
                {
                    die("read");
                }

            case 0:
                fprintf(stderr, "%s: EOF on stdin\n", nowtime());
                stdineof = 1;
                if (opos.write_ptr == opos.read_ptr)
                {
                    //everything was written to socket -> we won't be writing enything else -> close the connection by sending FIN
                    Shutdown(sockfd, SHUT_WR);
                }
                break;

            default:
                fprintf(stderr, "%s: read %ld bytes from stdin\n", nowtime(), nbytes);
                //move the read pointer with bytes writen
                opos.read_ptr += nbytes;
                //now those bytes could be writen to socket
                FD_SET(sockfd, &wset);
            }
        }

        if (FD_ISSET(sockfd, &rset))
        {
            switch ((nbytes = read(sockfd, ipos.read_ptr, &inbuf[BSIZE] - ipos.read_ptr)))
            {
            case -1:
                perror("read");
                if (errno != EWOULDBLOCK)
                {
                    die("read");
                }

            case 0:
                fprintf(stderr, "%s: EOF on socket\n", nowtime());
                if (stdineof)
                {
                    //normal termination (client EOF)
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    //RST from peer
                    die("str_cli: server terminated prematurely");
                }
                break;

            default:
                fprintf(stderr, "%s: read %ld bytes from socket\n", nowtime(), nbytes);
                //move the read pointer with bytes read
                ipos.read_ptr += nbytes;
                //those bytes could be writen to file
                FD_SET(STDOUT_FILENO, &wset);
            }
        }

        if (FD_ISSET(STDOUT_FILENO, &wset) && (nbytes = ipos.read_ptr - ipos.write_ptr) > 0)
        {
            //the stdout is writeable and there are some bytes to write
            switch ((nactual = write(STDOUT_FILENO, ipos.write_ptr, nbytes)))
            {
            case -1:
                perror("write");
                if (errno != EWOULDBLOCK)
                {
                    die("write");
                }
            default:
                fprintf(stderr, "%s: wrote %ld bytes to stdout\n", nowtime(), nactual);
                ipos.write_ptr += nactual;
                if (ipos.write_ptr == ipos.read_ptr)
                {
                    //back to beginning buffer if all was writen to stdout
                    ipos.write_ptr = ipos.read_ptr = inbuf;
                }
            }
        }

        if (FD_ISSET(sockfd, &wset) && ((nbytes = opos.read_ptr - opos.write_ptr) > 0))
        {
            //the socket is writeable and there are some bytes to write
            switch ((nactual = write(sockfd, opos.write_ptr, nbytes)))
            {
            case -1:
                perror("write");
                if (errno != EWOULDBLOCK)
                {
                    die("write");
                }

            default:
                fprintf(stderr, "%s wrote %ld bytes to socket\n", nowtime(), nactual);
                opos.write_ptr += nactual;
                if (opos.write_ptr == opos.read_ptr)
                {
                    //back to beginning buffer if all was send/writen to socket
                    opos.read_ptr = opos.write_ptr = outbuf;
                    if (stdineof)
                    {
                        //EOF, could send its FIN
                        Shutdown(sockfd, SHUT_WR);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `select` ignores `O_NONBLOCK` but it does not change the fact that the socket is in fact still a non blocking one. *why to bother setting socket non-blocking when select() blocks anyway*. Why indeed. Have you seen code that does that? There probably are such uses cases but it's probably also not the common case.

Comment: @kaylum well, I can give you an example from Addison Wesley : UNIXNetwork ProgrammingVolume 1. See edits. I think its rather complex example, but this example is the reason I am asking

Comment: @kaylum All code that uses non-blocking sockets has to do that, otherwise the sockets can block. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This is rather theoretical question. If sockets I/O (either read or write) is set to O_NONBLOCK, but then this socket is set in fd_set to select() which blocks (waiting for an event the file descriptor become either readable or writable), then that socket is blocking anyway (due to the select())?

The `select` is blocking. The socket is still non-blocking.

> Why would I set the socket to be non-blocking, when even the blocking (default) version once become readable (or writable) (thanks to select()), won't block, because the select() said it has data to read (or write) and thus the socket is able to perform its operation with that data without blocking.

No, no, no! That is not a safe assumption. There is no guarantee that a subsequent `read` or `write` will not block. You must set the socket non-blocking if you need a future guarantee that a later operation will not block.

> So why to bother setting socket non-blocking when select() blocks anyway?

Because you don't want operations on the socket to block. The `select` function does not guarantee that a future operation won't block and people have gotten burnt by making that assumption in the past.

For example, you do `select` on a UDP socket and it says that a receive won't block. But before you call `recv`, the administrator enables UDP checksums which were previously disabled. Guess what, now your `recv` will block if the checksum was incorrect on the only received datagram.

Unless you think you could have foreseen every way something like that could happen, and you definitely can't, you must set the socket non-blocking if you do not wish it to block.

Comment: What do you mean the `read` *can* block even after `select()` said it has some data to read? What is then `select()` for, when it gives these buggy assumption then? I thought `select()` *returns* when, and only when, it got some I/O **event** which kernel manage. So if a file descriptor got an *event*, then there is no reason to *block*. The state machine is simple in select(). Got some data (via some io event)? -> returned. Nop? ->  block. Why would subsequent calls should blocks (according to your statement)?  When this is job of select() ?

Comment: @milanHrabos It's just like checking for disk space before doing a write. If the disk is full, you may want to wait until there's disk space available. But the presence of disk space *when you checked* doesn't guarantee that a subsequent write will have enough disk space. The `select` function is just a status-reporting function that tells you about the past. It does not provide any guarantees about future operations. I explained why a subsequent call might block -- something you didn't think of might happen in between.

Comment: @milanHrabos If you're confident you can think of every possible bizarre scenario that could conceivably happen on all systems, past, present and future, then go ahead and roll the dice. But people have been seriously burned by making that assumption. A very severe Linux inetd DoS attack was an example of precisely this mistake.

Comment: Ok you got point. But we are talking about small amount of time, between `select()` returns, and `read` starts to perform. Usually those are subsequent calls, immediately one after another, so the time span should be really small. But you are right, it exists

Comment: @milanHrabos the process can be preempted between the select and the read, and that "small amount of time" can be made as large as necessary. But, even if you set the non-blocking flag, some other process who shares the same open socket via *another* file descriptor can turn the non-blocking flag off, and your read will still block. Morality: use `recv(MSG_DONTWAIT)` if you can (non-standard, but supported on most Unix platforms).

Answer (score 2):

`select` ignores the non-blocking flag on the file descriptor because it doesn't make any sense for it to pay attention to it.

- `select` is (potentially) checking mulitple file descriptor simultaneously, which might have different non-blocking flags.  Which should it pay attention to?
- `select` has its own explicit timeout that determines if the call is blocking or non-blocking, or blocking for a limited time.

Arguably, having a non-blocking "state" flag you can set on a file descriptor is a bad design -- it would be better to specify on each call whether you want blocking or non-blocking.  You can in fact do that if you use `recv` and `send` instead of `read` and `write`.  All that setting "nonblocking" on a file descriptor really does is that it makes calls that don't otherwise specify blocking or nonblocking, nonblocking.

Comment: I know there is no relation between non-blocking socket and blocking `select()` operation. (The operation knows nothing about its `fd`s). But the *overall* program appears as blocking because of the `select()`. So why to bother settings `fd`s to being non-block and in conjunction use them with `select()` ?

Comment: If you just want a blocking or non-blocking read, why are you using select at all?

Comment: "a non-blocking state flag [...] is a bad design" especially since it's a single flag for both read and write -- when running `foo | bar | baz` in a terminal, `baz` cannot do non-blocking i/o on its stdout without breaking the stdin of `foo`. Sockets have `MSG_DONTWAIT`, but pipes and ttys have nothing like that.

Comment: and the flag is not really set on the file descript*or*, but on the file descript*ion* -- all the fds referring to the same open socket or file share the same `O_NONBLOCK` flag.

Comment: @milanHrabos The program blocks, but it doesn't block *on the socket*. It's operations *on the socket* are non-blocking (we hope, assuming it was coded competently).

Comment: @milanHrabos: The difference between blocking on a socket operation and blocking on `select` is that when blocking on `select`, you can block on several types of socket operations (read/write) and on several sockets at once. You are right that there is no reason to use `select` when waiting for a single type of socket operation on a single socket, as you could use a blocking socket operation for this just as well. But if you want to block on a read/write or if several sockets are involved, then you will need `select` to block on all at once.

Comment: @milanHrabos: As already stated in the other answer, it is not guaranteed that a socket operation will not block, even if `select` suggests otherwise. Therefore, if you want to ensure that the socket operation will not block, you will have to set the socket itself to nonblocking. This will probably only be an issue in very rare cases, but in these rare cases, it may cause your program to stop responding, due to a socket operation blocking forever.